# Shellhub connect to device using SSHID

Tags: ssh, nat, ssh-tunnel, nat-traversal

I have installed shellhub and configured the ssh port to 2222 for shellhub because i have ssh-server running on port 22
i tried to connect to one of my devices using its SSHID using the command bellow :

```
ssh mgpu@mgpu.e8-39-35-30-bc-a9@myshellhub.com
```

but got :  `Permission denied, please try again.`

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After reading shellhub.io [documentation](https://docs.shellhub.io), i should use the ssh port configured while installing shellhub server not the ssh port of the destination computer.
The right command to use is

```
ssh mgpu@mgpu.e8-39-35-30-bc-a9@myshellhub.com -p 2222
```